# SQL query returning multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have three database tables:

```
system_profile 

id  manufacturer    model   name      total_physical_memory
12345   my_pc           5000    DGS       3219206144

device

id      version   date_created      device_id      instance 
2828493 0         2013-10-13 20:13:00   12345      q 
2828494 1         2013-10-13 xxxxx      12345      e
2828495 2         2013-10-13 aaaaa      12345          r    
2828496 3         2013-10-13 ccccc      12345      r 


hw_profile

id     manufacturer model   name      disk            device_id
12345  my_pc            5000      ABC 2 gb        12345
```

The hw_profile and system_profile tables are linked by primary key "id"

The hw_profile and device tables are linked by a device_id.

I am trying select to "get just the system_profile.total_physical_memory":

```
SELECT system_profile.total_physical_memory
FROM system_profile, hw_profile, device
WHERE hw_profile.id = system_profile.id
AND device.device_id = hw_profile.device_id
```

This query is not working (I am getting multiple results) back.

I need to return "just" system_profile.total_physical_memory (3219206144)

I have tried various left joins, exists - but no success.

A clear example would be great (plus some aspirin).

Thanks

Miles.

Comment: why you neet to join all three tables if you just want total_physical_memory ?

Comment: Do you have the id of the system you want to query?  I don't see the reason for doing any JOINs

Comment: I need to use the device_id to get 'to the total_physical_memory'

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to join to tables whose data is not used in any way. Just do a `SELECT total_physical_memory FROM system_profile`.

Comment: The background to answering this question is that I need to use the device_id to get to the total_physical_memory

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need join if you are getting data from single table.

In case you want to apply some condition based on other tables, try this query :
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT
            system_profile.total_physical_memory
          FROM system_profile
              JOIN hw_profile 
        ON(system_profile.id = hw_profile.id)
              JOIN device
        ON(device.device_id = hw_profile.device_id)";

You can also use LEFT JOIN rather than JOIN in case your application need this.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 SELECT sp.total_physical_memory
 FROM system_profile sp 
 INNER JOIN  device d ON d.device_id = sp.id
 INNER JOIN hw_profile hp ON hp.device_id = d.device_id;
```

Note: if the data is related to each table the you need to join the table , otherwise you simply select the total_physical_memory for a particular id , like:

```
 SELECT total_physical_memory
 FROM system_profile where id = <some_id>;
```